# Install and access to phpmyadmin on host server

Tags: phpmyadmin, ovh

My website is on host server (OVH), actually I'm using the website https://phpmyadmin.ovh.net to admin my database, but I can't configure how I want the work environment, so the admins of OVH told my I have to install my ownn phpadmin.

I've :

- downloaded phpMyAdmin-4.7.8-all-languages
- unzipped it on the root of my website renamed my "config.sample.inc.php" to "config.inc.php"
- configured my file with :

> ```
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '[MY_DB_SERVER]';
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = '[MY_DB_USER]';
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '[MY_DB_PASS]';
> ```

I also tried with :

> ```
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '[MY_DB_USER]';
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '[MY_DB_PASS]';
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
> ```

But when I tri to access to the user interface, it's clearly not working... Have I missed something ?

[image]

Comment: You closed the string on config? There is a missing `'` at the end of the values.

Comment: yes, was just a copy/past error when I replaced the real values, error corrected

Comment: An error 500 should be logged in more detail in your webserver error log. What does that say?